# Can you change/redirect a django form's function by passing in your own function?

Tags: python, django, paypal, e-commerce, django-paypal

I'm dealing with django-paypal and want to change the button src images.  So I went the the conf.py file in the source and edited the src destination.  However, I really want to leave the source alone, and I noticed that the

```
class PayPalPaymentsForm(forms.Form):
```

has

```
def get_image(self):
    return {
        (True, self.SUBSCRIBE): SUBSCRIPTION_SANDBOX_IMAGE,
        (True, self.BUY): SANDBOX_IMAGE,
        (True, self.DONATE): DONATION_SANDBOX_IMAGE,
        (False, self.SUBSCRIBE): SUBSCRIPTION_IMAGE,
        (False, self.BUY): IMAGE,
        (False, self.DONATE): DONATION_IMAGE,
    }[TEST, self.button_type]
```

which handles all the image src destinations.  Since changing this def in the source is worse than changing conf, I was wondering if there was a way to pass in customized defs you make like passing in initial arguments in forms?  This way no source code is changed, and I can customize the get_image def as much as I need.

passing in def something like this?

```
def get_image(self):
    ....
    ....
paypal = {
    'amount': 10,
    'item_name': 'test1',
    'item_number': 'test1_slug',

    # PayPal wants a unique invoice ID
    'invoice': str(uuid.uuid4()), 
}
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal, get_image)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just subclass `PayPalPaymentsForm` and override `get_image`.

Answer (score 1):

As seen here: https://github.com/dcramer/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/conf.py

You have to change PAYPAL_IMAGE, or PAYPAL_SUBSCRIPTION_IMAGE, ... in your settings.py.